# What could be going on?

Tags: phd

So I submitted a manuscript to a public health journal under Cambridge press sometime in October last year. Actually beginning of October.
Since its submission, my manuscript has gone through several stages in the review process, as indicated by the online submission system. It initially went from "Awaiting admin processing" to "Awaiting reviewer nomination," and then to "Awaiting reviewer selection." After that, it entered the "Under review" stage, but subsequently returned to "Awaiting reviewer selection." Surprisingly, it stayed in that stage for only a day before transitioning back to the "Under review" status. However, for the past five months, it has once again been stuck at "Awaiting reviewer selection."

Given the extended duration and multiple transitions in the review process, I have tried reaching out to the editor through various correspondences but have not received any response thus far. This lack of communication has left me uncertain about the current status of my manuscript and the estimated timeline for its review.

Comment: Ask yourself this: If you knew the answer, would that mean you could do anything with that knowledge? Instead you could have spent that time on cooking a meal for a loved one, just relax, writing the next article. All of that would be more productive. I know it is hard, but once you submitted an article, you need to forget it existed until you get the final answer.